# Get Dynamic menu in Einstein Bot From An Apex Call

Tags: apex, einstein, einstein-chatbot

I would like in my einstein bot to make an Apex Call that will return a list of value that will be display to the user

so I defined an Input which is the user Email
and I defined an output which is a list of value

my code (pretty simple) is the following:

```
public without sharing class ChatBot_RetrieveTrips {
    public class ChatBotInput{
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public string guestEmail;
    }
    
    public class ChatBotOutput{
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public string[] tripResults2;
        
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod(Label = 'Get Past trips' description='Get a list of Trips From BO for specific user')
    public static string[] GetTripList (List <String> guestEmail){
        system.debug(guestEmail[0]);
        String[] TripList = new List<String>();
        TripList.add('Paris');
        TripList.add('New York');
        TripList.add('Madrid');
        system.debug(TripList);
        return TripList;
        
    }
```

Now in my Einstein bot I defined properly my input but I cannot define the output as a list

[image]

It is grey out ..
What I do not understand ?

thx you

Answer (score 0):

I'm just exploring doing this myself and I believe you need to define the input and output parameters as lists to cater for invocable bulkification? Additionally, these need to be lists of the input and output type (wrapper classes) i.e.

```
public static List<ChatBotOutput> GetTripList (List <ChatBotInput> guestEmail)
```